# Writing a final output to geodatabase in Model Builder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder

I wanted to write a Model Builder but I am not sure how to do save the final output as a geodatabase.

[image]

I am working on to classify each imagery (about 83 of them) and then sent it to a polygon and then rename it to the same name from the original file to save to the geodatabase.

It is working but I could not get the final output to change the pathname to the geodatabase I wanted.

Comment: Is your output polygon feature parameter for the Raster to Polygon tool pointing to your geodatabase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attached model has an iterator which loops through a workspace and performs the various tasks.  I added parse path to split the name from the iterator feature path so that it can be used to name the output.  Make sure to specify `Name` in the parse path GUI.  Add a new variable to your model `outFGDB`.  Then put it all together in the Raster to Polygon output parameter using the following syntax `%outFGDB%\%Value%_new`.  The end result for each iteration of the model will be a new polygon with a unique name placed in a file geodatabase.

[image]

Comment: I test it and it worked however at the end there was an error :ERROR 000875: Output polygon features: C:\Users\Robert.Pollock\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\%outFGDB%\ast_l1b_00301132004175715_20101206173613_5997_ndvi_new's workspace is an invalid output workspace.


ERROR 000581: Invalid parameters.
Failed to execute (Raster to Polygon).
Failed at Fri Jun 13 10:33:29 2014 (Elapsed Time: 2.00 seconds)

Comment: Make sure to specify the output FGDB workspace in the `outFGDB` variable.  This would be the full path of a file geodatabase e.g. C:\Users\Robert.Pollock\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb.  Then, in the raster to polygon output add `%outFGDB%\%Value%_new`.  It looks like you are adding too many output variables.

Comment: Problem solved, Aaron. Had to looked at really carefully and fixed it.

Comment: Aaron, do I need to add a variable to save each remap tables ? Will that work ?

Comment: I do not follow @PROBERT.  Could you please provide more details?

Comment: what I want when you reclassify each raster I want to save each remap table so I can join each table later.

Comment: @PROBERT If your original Question has an Accept-ed Answer it will be best to research/ask the supplementary one separately.